# Is there any different between Android 2.3 and 4.0 for decode XML file by PULL?

Tags: android, xml, pull

I just found a bug for my APP, which is run normally in Android 4.0 , but will crash in Android 2.3 , I trace it and found the problem is decode XML files

the XML files format is

```
<a>
 <b></b>
</a>
<a>
 <b></b>
</a>
```

it is fine when I use PULL in Android 4.0 ,but in Android 2.3 , I found out that the format has to be :

```
*<AAA>
 <a>
   <b></b>
 </a>
 <a>
   <b></b>
 </a>
</AAA>*
```

it means that the XML must be a tree in Android 2.3 then we could use PULL , otherwise it will crash ?

So is there any document from Google to prove that ? I'm looking for that .

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that all properly formed XML documents require a root element (`AAA` in your case). Obviously, some parsers may have the ability to suppress this error and just read as per normal, such as the parser present in Android 4.0. Please see this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) with regards to XML root elements.

EDIT: Google Document

Please find the [Google document](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) that links directly to an XML specifications sheet (It's the "See Also" document/link).

Comment: It seems XML don't have to have a root element in Android 4.0, PULL runs fine in that~ And Sax seems could handle that problem . Thanks a lot ~~!

Comment: Honestly that sounds like a bug in Android 4.0 to me. A malformed XML file should not be processed as if it were OK.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer a parser that doesn't crash because of a lack of a root element (Maybe it throws a warning to log?), over a parser that just crashes.